# How to change mouse speed of the login window?

Tags: macos, mouse

I prefer a fast tracking speed for mouse on my MacBook.

[image]

However, this setting is only good for the logged in user. When I logged out, the mouse is slow again.

How can I change the mouse tracking speed in the login window (i.e. when all users are logged out)?

Comment: Have you tried the suggested answer here? https://superuser.com/questions/179288/os-x-how-do-i-alter-preferences-for-the-login-window?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @Elliott Don't think this works anymore, at least not without disabling SIP.

Comment: Anyway, what need do you have for the mouse on the login screen? To select one of the accounts it's enough to type the first few letters of the (displayed) user name.

Comment: @nohillside it's the need of tuning my machine to work in a way that I prefer...

Answer (score 1):

If you are saying that you would like to set the mouse tracking speed for all users of the system I do not believe there is a way to do that.  Each will have his/her own preference.

If you are saying that when you set your preference and then log out/log in under the same user and unexpectedly find that your preferences are not retained then there should be a fix.

Likely cause ,either:

The the permissions on the preference file are set incorrectly --  This might be fixed in disk utility -- repair permissions. Logout and then login.

or

The permission file is corrupt.  You should move it to the desktop, logout, login and set the permissions. Should stick now.  I believe the preference is stored here:
~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.driver.AppleHIDMouse.plist

Comment: The setting is stored in ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist, not com.apple.driver.AppleHIDMouse.plist.

Comment: I'd like to change the mouse speed in the login window (i.e., when all users are logged out).

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. Even if all users' mouse speeds are set faster than default, it's still slow on the login screen. Very annoying :/

Answer (score 0):

Run in terminal:

```
defaults -currentHost write NSGlobalDomain com.apple.trackpad.scaling -float #.#
defaults write NSGlobalDomain com.apple.trackpad.scaling -float #.#`
```

1.0 is about the middle of the GUI.

Check current value set by the slider in the GUI with:

`defaults read | grep trackpad.scaling`

This is for the trackpad, adapt as necessary if using a mouse

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried it, but maybe setting the mouse tracking speed for the root user will do the trick. You need to enable the root account first: https://support.apple.com/hr-hr/HT204012

Then log in as root, open the system preferences and modify the tracking options.