# How to select login user with keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, system-settings, macos

I have a 4K monitor and before I have logged in, the mouse moves really slowly on the user login screen.  Once logged in, I have configured the Tracking speed in the Mouse System Preferences to move fast.  Since there is [no known way to configure the default Tracking Speed](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/94554/19937) before I've logged in, is there a way to select a login user without clicking on the user and using the keyboard to select a login?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to choose any of the login users either with an *arbitrary* <kbd>arrow</kbd> key (if the user name is somewhere in the middle more than one hit is necessary) & <kbd>enter</kbd> or by entering the first letter of the user name (or the first two if you have several names starting with the same letter) & <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Then enter the password.